# Does glibc work on bare metal or RTOS platforms?

Tags: embedded, glibc, newlib

Embedded experts, is this possible without major modifications?

I'm building firmware that has both a Linux kernel and a minimal RTOS that runs when resuming from sleep. The same toolchain, aarch64-linux-gnu, is used for both Linux and RTOS code. The reason why it doesn't need a separate bare metal toolchain for RTOS is because the vendor has their own stripped down C runtime which they use instead of glibc.

But that poorly made C runtime is missing a lot of functions, so we want to use a more full featured one. We could use newlib but that would require a 2nd toolchain, which want to avoid.

But I can't find any bare metal or RTOS project using glibc. Currently, it can build with glibc, but crashes real soon, almost certainly because we didn't call the glibc initialization code:

```
_start
   __libc_start_main  
     __libc_csu_init   (call C++ constructors for global variables)
     main
```

https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/aarch64/start.S
https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/master/csu/libc-start.c

But looking at __libc_start_main, it's a lot more complicated than newlib. Seems it depends on a lot of Linux facilities that don't exist:

1. dynamic linking?   _dl_aux_init
2. pthreads   __pthread_initialize_minimal

On the positive side, glibc does let you override sbrk and write, which are weakly defined, so that they can call the device driver code directly instead of making syscalls to the non-existent kernel

Update: working for us means

```
1. malloc
2. printf,write to serial port, but not to actual files
3. C++ globals initialized correctly
4. no threading
```

Comment: glibc requires a POSIX OS. It is I think entirely possible to tell GCC not to link _any_ standard libraries or start-up code then to explicitly link your own C library such as Newlib and crt0 startup code. However, such an arrangement is the no different than most standalone GNU toolchains.  Newlib supports all your mentioned requirements, so why do you need glibc?

Comment: I know Newlib will work, is simpler, and have used it for STM32 development. The firmware build requires aarch64-linux-gnu (glibc) toolchain to build the userspace programs. So we're trying to reuse that for the RTOS portion.Otherwise, we'll need to convince the hardware vendor to use 2 tool chains or 1 multilib toolchain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In glibc, `malloc` depends on a low-level allocator such as `sbrk` (or `mmap`). You can probably fake something like `sbrk` on a bare-metal target, but you would have to stub out all the indirect `malloc` dependencies (including multi-threading support).

The glibc `printf` implementation is coupled to the `fopen` implementation, which depends on `dlopen` for loading character set conversion code (the `gconv` modules). This even applies to the statically linked case. There is really no way to escape the dynamic linker without some far-reaching changes.

C++ initialization should be fairly easy to get right, even for bare-metal targets. I do not think you need any libc for that, just a little bit of startup code that matches what your target needs. (On some targets, it is sufficient to call the magic `_init` function before your application.) glibc has some elaborate facilities for that as well, but they are for supporting dynamic linking and `dlopen`/`dlclose`. For statically linked binaries, they are not needed.

A high-quality port of glibc to a non-Linux. non-GNU operating system is definitely a lot of work. If the target is bare-metal or a non-POSIX RTOS, you probably have to start with a POSIX shim layer. Even then, the result will be a not-quite-glibc target, and you still need a separate toolchain.

It may be better to go with newlib (or the existing RTOS libc) and obtain the missing libc functionality via [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) and similar projects.

Comment: [printf] depends on dlopen - aha, that would be a show stopper. Thanks for confirming my suspicions about dynamic linking. I suppose that means newlib doesn't support character set conversion. I will abandon this seemingly expedient solution of reusing the glibc toolchain

Comment: To ble clear, the `printf` dependency on `dlopen` is really something that is glibc-specific. Other implementations do not have this issue.